# How to create a tinder-like swipeable card stack

Tags: android

I would like to ask about the tinder-like swipeable card stack for my application. The point of it is that users will be able to see photos and swipe when they want to see another one. I'm already sending and receiving images to and from webservice and I have been trying some libraries that could manage to do this (googled 'swipedeck' and 'swipecard') but non of them either offered enough flexibility to customize actions fully, or were not working with ImageViews, only TextView.

Now I'm new at this, but I figured that there has to be some kind of RecyclerView, TabLayout or some other implementation that would make it possible to do this and would include also transitions/sliding effects between pictures. I just need someone to point me in the right direction.

Could you please help me by posting your ideas? It would help a lot, and I do not need any specific code parts, I will do my research later on based on your ideas. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the official guide on creating sliding screens using Viewpager. This should help you get started : [Using Viewpager for Screen Slides](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)

Comment: this is something that i was looking for, thanks a lot buddy!

Answer (score 1):

There is a project in github that does exactly that - it's called "TinderStack", and you can find it at https://github.com/lawloretienne/TinderStack

Comment: thanks mate, it looks good, but again its just another library... i will look at it tho ;)